# Connect Oracle using SqlPlus by Domain User

Tags: oracle, oracleclient

Client and Server machines are under Domain. I am trying to connect orace db using SqlPlus tool. I am getting

```
ERROR:
ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied
```

though username and pwd is right.

Connect Command :

```
SqlPlus DomainName\UserName/passowrd@school
```

Database address in tnsnames.ora

```
school =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = machinename)(PORT = 1521))
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVICE_NAME = PRD)
    )
  )
```

Is there any wrong in database address? Way of connect?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 3):

There is no need of specifying DomainName in front of a username in sqlplus to connect to an instance.

```
sqlplus username/password@connect_identifier
```

Also check these options

1. Try to use use IP address instead of computer name in tnsnames.ora
2. Set parameter `NAMES.DEFAULT_DOMAIN` in `sqlnet.ora`
3. Specify a fully qualified computer name (`computername.domain`) in `tnsnames.ora`